# Argument mismatch in python constructor

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written a python class whose constructor takes two lists as arguments.

```
class nn:
    def __init__(layer_dimensions=[],activations=[]):

        self.parameters = {} 
        self.cache = []      
        self.activations= []

        initialize_parameters(layer_dimensions)
        initialize_activations(activations)

net = nn(list([2,15,2]),list(['relu','sigmoid']))
```

On trying to pass two lists as arguments in the constructor I get the following error:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes from 0 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

The error states that 3 arguments have been passed but its quite obvious that I've passed only 2.

Comment: You're missing `self` as the first argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed self as instance from which class method is invoked is automatically passed.

```
class nn:
    def __init__(self, layer_dimensions=[],activations=[]):

        self.parameters = {} 
        self.cache = []      
        self.activations= []

        initialize_parameters(layer_dimensions)
        initialize_activations(activations)

net = nn(list([2,15,2]),list(['relu','sigmoid']))
```

Answer (score 1):

I do believe you are missing a self in your constructor

```
class nn:
    def __init__(self, layer_dimensions=[],activations=[]):

        self.parameters = {} 
        self.cache = []      
        self.activations= []

        initialize_parameters(layer_dimensions)
        initialize_activations(activations)

net = nn(list([2,15,2]),list(['relu','sigmoid']))
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, it's not a good practice that default arguments to be mutable. You can read more about it [here](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments).